# awk Merge two files based on common field and print similarities and differences

Tags: awk, merge

I have two files I would like to merge into a third but I need to see both when they share a common field and where they differ.Since there are minor differences in other fields, I cannot use a diff tool and I thought this could be done with awk.

File 1:

```
aWonderfulMachine             1   mlqsjflk          
AnotherWonderfulMachine     2   mlksjf          
YetAnother WonderfulMachine 3   sdg         
TrashWeWon'tBuy             4   jhfgjh          
MoreTrash                     5   qsfqf         
MiscelleneousStuff           6  qfsdf           
MoreMiscelleneousStuff       7  qsfwsf
```

File2:

```
aWonderfulMachine             22    dfhdhg          
aWonderfulMachine             23    dfhh            
aWonderfulMachine             24    qdgfqf          
AnotherWonderfulMachine     25    qsfsq         
AnotherWonderfulMachine     26    qfwdsf            
MoreDifferentStuff           27    qsfsdf           
StrangeStuffBought           28    qsfsdf
```

Desired output:

```
aWonderfulMachine   1   mlqsjflk    aWonderfulMachine   22  dfhdhg
                                     aWonderfulMachine  23  dfhdhg
                                     aWonderfulMachine  24  dfhh
AnotherWonderfulMachine 2   mlksjf  AnotherWonderfulMachine 25  qfwdsf
                                       AnotherWonderfulMachine  26  qfwdsf
File1
YetAnother WonderfulMachine 3   sdg         
TrashWeWon'tBuy             4   jhfgjh          
MoreTrash                     5   qsfqf         
MiscelleneousStuff           6   qfsdf          
MoreMiscelleneousStuff       7   qsfwsf         
File2                   
MoreDifferentStuff          27  qsfsdf          
StrangeStuffBought          28  qsfsdf
```

I have tried a few awks scripts here and there, but they are either based on two fields only, and I don't know how to modify the output, or they delete the duplicates based on two fields only, etc (I am new to this and awk syntax is tough).
Thank you much in advance for your help.

Comment: Will any key in file 2 every be duplicated in file 1? I.e. is the possibly a many-to-many relationship or is it strictly one-to-many? In any case, awk may not be the optimal tool for this purpose, it's array operators are a little weak, and you'll more or less have to implement this by reading both files into big associative arrays and then bash away at them.

Comment: Yes, there may be duplicate keys in both files.

Comment: By the way, a certain amount of the confusion this question has engendered could have been avoided if you had specified that you were using tabs to deliminate fields in both input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can come very close using these three commands:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
join -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This assumes a shell, such as Bash, that supports process substitution (`<()`). If you're using a shell that doesn't, the files would need to be pre-sorted.

To do this in AWK:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="\t"; flag=1; file1=ARGV[1]; file2=ARGV[2] }
FNR == NR { lines1[$1] = $0; count1[$1]++; next }  # process the first file
{   # process the second file and do output
    lines2[$1] = $0;
    count2[$1]++;
    if ($1 != prev) { flag = 1 };
    if (count1[$1]) {
        if (flag) printf "%s ", lines1[$1];
        else printf "\t\t\t\t\t"
        flag = 0;
        printf "\t%s\n", $0
    }
    prev = $1
}
END { # output lines that are unique to one file or the other
    print "File 1: " file1
    for (i in lines1) if (! (i in lines2)) print lines1[i]
    print "File 2: " file2
    for (i in lines2) if (! (i in lines1)) print lines2[i]
}
```

To run it:

```
$ ./script.awk file1 file2
```

The lines won't be output in the same order that they appear in the input files. The second input file (file2) needs to be sorted since the script assumes that similar lines are adjacent. You will probably want to adjust the tabs or other spacing in the script. I haven't done much in that regard.

Comment: The `join` method will work even if keys are duplicated in both input files. In such a case, The AWK script will only output the last of a set of similar lines from file1 (duplicates in file2 are handled as expected).

Comment: Thank you! The script is doing something right but the first part (put rows with identical key on same line) is staggered in a way that I can't interpret. It might have something to do with fields separators (here, tabs). I have had some unfortunate experiences trying to modify field separators on a script I found to do some other job. I find awk's syntax a bit hard to get right.(Sorry I had to get off the computer for an hour).

Comment: @Trying: Try adding `else printf "\t\t\t\t\t"` as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: My first field is actually a concatenation of several fields so it reads as a "comment" sort of field. The merging is done on the first word of the string.

Comment: I am not sure I was very clear. The fields look like this: "this is a sentence as a first field" tab "22" tab "some other field" tab "yet another field"

Comment: @Trying: Try `./scriptname.awk -F '\t' file1 file2` to split only on tabs if splitting on spaces as well as tabs isn't working correctly. Is there more than one tab between fields?

Comment: @Trying: I added the field separator into the code so you don't have to specify it on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! I am going to save days of work now. The only last question I would have for you is about the join solution. It seemed to work, except that I could not redirect the output to a third file (especially for join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)), and since it is 1,000 entries long, I could not access the entirety of the results. I have been all over the internet about this and have not found why >file3 does not work.

Comment: @Trying: `join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3` should work just fine. If you're redirecting all three `join` commands to one file, you may want to use `>>` instead of `>` so the output is appended to the file instead of overwriting it. You could also do `{ join ...; join ...; join ...; } > file3` to do them all at once (replacing the `...` with the correct arguments, of course).

Comment: @Dennis : join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3 throws me an error to the effect that file1 and file2 are not in the expected order. If I remove the redirection, I get the output. I am using bash.

Comment: @Trying: Does it do that with the sample data you provided or only with your real data? It works just fine for me. What do you get from this command: `echo $LC_COLLATE`? Also, try using `join -t $'\t' ...`

Comment: @Dennis: The join problem is with real data. And echo $LC_COLLATE gives me a blank line. As for this advice : join -t $'\t'... it tells me the first file is not in the expected order. If I reverse the order of the files, it says file2 is not in the expected order.

Comment: It is fine with the sample data.

Comment: @Trying: Sorry, what does the `locale` command say for `LC_COLLATE`? You may need to add `-t $'\t'` to each of the `sort` commands as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (albeit with hardcoded file names):

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"; 
    readfile(ARGV[1], s1); 
    readfile(ARGV[2], s2); 
    ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = "/dev/null"
}
END{
    for (k in s1) {
    if ( s2[k] ) printpair(k,s1,s2);
    }
    print "file1:"
    for (k in s1) {
    if ( !s2[k] ) print s1[k];
    }
    print "file2:"
    for (k in s2) {
    if ( !s1[k] ) print s2[k];
    }
}
function readfile(fname, sary) {
    while ( getline <fname ) {
    key = $1;
    if (sary[key]) {
        sary[key] = sary[key] "\n" $0; 
    } else {
        sary[key] = $0;
    };
    }
    close(fname);
}
function printpair(key, s1, s2) {
    n1 = split(s1[key],l1,"\n");
    n2 = split(s2[key],l2,"\n");
    for (i=1; i<=max(n1,n2); i++){
    if (i==1) {
        b = l1[1]; 
        gsub("."," ",b);
    }
    if (i<=n1) { f1 = l1[i] } else { f1 = b };
    if (i<=n2) { f2 = l2[i] } else { f2 = b };
    printf("%s\t%s\n",f1,f2);
    }
}
function max(x,y){ z = x; if (y>x) z = y; return z; }
```

Not particularly elegant, but it handles many-to-many cases.

Comment: You could have filenames as command-line arguments with this change: `BEGIN { readfile(ARGV[1], s1); readfile(ARGV[2], s2); ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = "/dev/null" }`

Comment: It is doing something right but the output does not take into account the tab separator and I don't know where to put it.

Comment: @Trying: Tab? What tab?!? *::looks at the comments on Dennis' answer::* Oh! **That** tab. Well, you could do the same thing Dennis did, replace the field separator in the BEGIN block; do so *before* the calls to readfile. Likewise if you want to use Dennis' clever little ARGV incantation.

Comment: I am sorry but I modified the BEGIN block so : "BEGIN { 
 FS="\t"; readfile(ARGV[1], s1); readfile(ARGV[2], s2); ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = "/dev/null" }"  and I am getting this as an output: "my field as a comment" TAB "22 the third field as comment" TAB "36", instead of "my field as comment" TAB "22" "my field as comment" TAB "36". That means I can't grab and sort those digits which I need. Silly me, hé?

Comment: @Trying: Um...probably we need to replace the spaces I was using to set off the two sides of the matching lines with a tab. Will edit. The change is the `printf` line in `printpair`.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not make a difference.